# Can HTML be executed while being read from or inserted into a textbox?

Tags: asp.net, html, antixsslibrary

I have a question regarding ANTIXSS implementation. If I was to read values from a textbox on a page and store it into a database directly and then read value from the database and insert it into a textbox, then is there a chance that the  tag or similar could be executed in the process ?
Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 1):

It is best to assume that all user inputted data is potentially malicious.  Don't encode input based on usage as your usage of the data may change - always encode user inputted values and you will have effectively removed any potential problems.

Comment: Always always always always ALWAYS. I don't care if it's in your admin control panel. ALWAYS. When I was younger I used to go around to websites, pasting linux shutdown commands/table wipes into text boxes, and hitting submit, waiting a few, and refreshing. It was endlessly entertaining.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment...
I AM NOT AS WELL EXPERIENCED AS YOU IN THE SITUATION. CAN YOU PLEASE GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE. THE REASON I ASK IS MY CLIENT HAS EMAIL ADDRESS FIELD AND HE BELIEVES THAT THERE IS NO NEED TO IMPLEMENT ANTIXSS AS HTML CODE INSERTED INTO A TEXTBOX SENT TO AN INSERT QUERY AND READ FROM THE DATABASE USING A SELECT QUERY SENT BACK TO THE TEXTBOX CANNOT BE EXECUTED IN THE PROCESS. REGARDS, ANDY.